# Selector name found in current argument registers: retain

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, crash-reports, hockeyapp

This crash seems to be happening daily, but I can't make it happened, and HockeyApp do not display any useful data.

[crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNZkm.png)

[crash load part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ5OM.png)

Comment: It's very hard to get any useful information from the screenshots you posted as the crash report does only contain unsymbolicated memory addresses.
In general, this looks like a memory management problems, most likely related to either dispatch queues or blocks. But to tell anything more, we'd need a fully symbolicated crash report.

Comment: I am having some trouble symbolicating this report, but I'll try and update ASAP, thank you!